# Why does the second term require $|x|\leq|y|$ not $|x|\leq y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

The book says that the relation $\sqrt{x^2-y^2} + \arccos\dfrac{x}{y} = 0$ where $y \neq 0$ implies $\left|x\right| \geq \left|y\right|$ and  $|x| \leq |y|$.

I understand that $x^2 - y^2 \geq 0$ from where $x^2 \geq y^2 \implies |x| \geq |y|$. But I cannot understand how to get the second constraint. What I can get is that $-1 \leq \dfrac{x}{y} \leq 1 \implies |x| \leq y$.

Comment: `What I can get is ...` Only if $y \gt 0$, otherwise you get $|x| \le -y$. Now combine the two.

Comment: $y^2$ is never negative, regardless of whether or not $y$ is positive or negative.  $|x|$ is never negative regardless of whether or not $y$ is positive or negative or if $x$ is positive or negative.  Tell me... is it possible for $|x|<y$ in the case that $y$ is negative?

Comment: $-1\le \frac xy\le 1\Rightarrow \left|\frac xy\right|\le 1$

Comment: $-1\le \frac {x}{y} \le 1 \implies -y\le x \le y$ only if $y>0.$ If $y< 0,$ it will flip the signs of the inequality and $-y\ge x \ge y$

Comment: Am I stupid guys? I really can't understand what is going on. @JMoravitz, it is impossible, so I can't understand is $\left | x \right | \lt y$ actually an eligible inequality?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov you can refer to my comment

Comment: It isn't an eligible inequality is what $|x|<y$ being impossible in the case that $y<0$ implies.  In other words, you made a mistake.  The mistake is as pointed out by other people that you are forgetting how directions of inequalities can change when multiplying or dividing by a negative value (*or possibly negative in this case*).

Comment: @JMoravitz, I am asking in general. Why is it not eligible as a separate, an individual inequality? There are a lot of ordered pairs that satisfy the inequality $\left | x \right | \lt y $ like $(-1, 1), (2, 3)$, etc.

Comment: In an attempt to rephrase what other users have said: $\left(-1\leq \frac{x}{y}\leq 1\right)\implies \begin{cases} -y\leq x\leq y&\text{in the case that}~y>0\\y\leq x\leq -y&\text{in the case that}~y<0\end{cases}$.  It is not always true that $-1\leq \frac{x}{y}\leq 1\implies -y\leq x\leq y$ in every case as evidenced by pairs such as $(3,-6)$ or $(-2,-6)$ etc... If we say an implication like this, we must either specify in what cases it actually works, or we must make the statement actually true for all cases.

Comment: It is eligible for a separate individual inequality, but *only with the caveat that it reminds the reader that it only works in certain restrictive scenarios*, what those restrictive scenarios are, and that there are feasible scenarios where it *doesn't* work.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I got it thanks! Write it as the answer if you wish

Answer (score 1):

Given that you accept $-1 \le \frac xy \le 1$ from the $\arccos$ function you need $|x| \le |y|$ to satisfy it.  Your version of $|x| \le y$ would fail for $x=-1,y=-2$ but $\arccos \frac {(-1)}{(-2)}$ is perfectly well defined.

Answer (score 0):

$-1 \le \frac xy \le 1$ then if $y > 0$ then $-y \le x \le y \implies |x| \le y=|y|$.

And if $y < 0$ then $-y \ge x \ge y \implies |x| \le -y = |y|$.